# Combing two PHP arrays with different structures while weeding out duplicate records

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, examples of the structures below:

Array #1 -- keys are stored in the first index of the array as the corresponding value.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => name
        [1] => time
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => Bob
        [1] => 20
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => Jack
        [1] => 25
    )
)
```

Array #2 -- each array has a numbered key and named key with the corresponding value being the same

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [name] => Bob
        [0] => Bob
        [time] => 20
        [1] => 20
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        [name] => Test
        [0] => Test
        [time] => 40
        [1] => 40
    )
)
```

Attempt:

```
foreach($arr as $record) {

    if(!in_array($record['name'], $names))
        $names[] = $record['name'];

}

foreach($csv as $rec) {

    if(!in_array($rec[0], $names))
        $names[] = $rec[0];

}
```

How can I combine these arrays, and weed out and duplicates based on the value of the name?

Comment: What is the duplication? Is it `[name] => Bob` and `[0] => Bob`?

Comment: No, in array #1 there is an array with [0] => Bob and in array #2 there is an array with [0] => Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, i added commands between the code.

```
//Array 1
$array1 = Array(
0 => Array(
    0 => "Bob",
    1 => 20,
),
1 => Array(
    0 => "Jack",
    1 => 25,
));

//Array 2
$array2 = Array(
0 => Array(
    "name" => "Bob",
    0 => "Bob",
    "time" => 20,
    1 => 20,
),
1 => Array(
    "name" => "Test",
    0 => "Test",
    "time" => 40,
    1 => 40,
));

//Function to search if the value already exists
function inArray($array, $search)
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$subArray)
    {
        if(in_array($search, $subArray))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }   

    return false;
}

$newArray = array();

//Loop over array1 length + array2 length   
for($i = 0 ; $i < (count($array1) + count($array2)) ; $i++)
{
    //Choose the array based on the counter ($i)
    if($i < count($array1))
    {
        $data       = $array1;
        $arrayIndex = $i;
    }
    else
    {
        $data       = $array2;
        $arrayIndex = $i - count($array1);
    }       

    //Check if array value exists
    if(!inArray($newArray,$data[$arrayIndex][0]))
    {
        //Add if it doesn't exists with the keys 'name' and 'time'
        $newArray[] = array('name' => $data[$arrayIndex][0], 'time'=> $data[$arrayIndex][1]);
    }       
}

print_r($newArray);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bob
            [time] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jack
            [time] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test
            [time] => 40
        )

)
```